# Formatting email id strings using regexp

Tags: plsql, oracle10g

I have a string with email addresses say for example

```
,abc@gmail.com, pqr@gmail.com, 123@gmail.com,

abc@gmail.com,, pqr@gmail.com, 123@gmail.com,xyz@gmail.com,
```

I want the out put to be

```
abc@gmail.com,pqr@gmail.com,123@gmail.com
abc@gmail.com,pqr@gmail.com,123@gmail.com,xyz@gmail.com
```

I tried many options but couldn't get the desired results ...sometimes with double commas, comma at the start and end of the string.

Can this be achieved in a single sql statement using regexp?

I am using Oracle 10g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with testdata as
  (select ',abc@gmail.com, pqr@gmail.com, 123@gmail.com,' as e from dual
   union all
   select 'abc@gmail.com,, pqr@gmail.com, 123@gmail.com,xyz@gmail.com,' from dual)
select TRIM(',' FROM REPLACE(REPLACE(e,' '),',,',','))
from testdata;

abc@gmail.com,pqr@gmail.com,123@gmail.com
abc@gmail.com,pqr@gmail.com,123@gmail.com,xyz@gmail.com
```

Comment: Thanks a ton...works well ...and I was struggling with regexp...but still wondering is there a way with regexp

Answer (score 0):

--with Regular Expression we can do like this.

```
WITH testdata AS
  (SELECT ',abc@gmail.com, pqr@gmail.com, 123@gmail.com,' AS e FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc@gmail.com,, pqr@gmail.com, 123@gmail.com,xyz@gmail.com,'
  FROM dual
  )
SELECT trim(','
FROM regexp_replace((regexp_replace(e,',|[[:space:]]',NULL)),'gmail.com','gmail.com,'))
FROM testdata
```